# Tips for writing 3D Collision detection with opengl

Tags: opengl, c++, collision-detection

I would like to any tips/articles/tutorials on how to write collision detection using OpenGL and C++ in 3D mainly just simple box collisions etc but also if there are any advanced resources that would be great to. i also don't wont to use any external library`s if possible.

thanks

Comment: I don't think the OpenGL part will actually make much of a difference. Oh, except you won't be using DXD3DVECTOR or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 3):

There will be huge amounts of resources out there, I dont know how much you know about current collision techniques, but a good idea if you're not familar with them could be to download Unity3D and play around with the buit-in physics engine (PhysX).

Box collisions are generally done using AABB's (Axis-Aligned Bounding Boxes), Sphere collisions are faster but obviously can't give you as good a representation for a box for example. Capsule colliders are elongated spheres and are very useful for characters and such.

You should also look for details on Terrain/BSP collision detection depending on what your needs are.

[Good simple tutorial for AABB's](http://wp.freya.no/3d-math-and-physics/simple-aabb-vs-aabb-collision-detection/)

Here are a few things I googled (but may not be pertinent)...

http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3383/simple_intersection_tests_for_games.php

[Bounding Sphere Collision](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/game-programming/collision-detection/simple-bounding-sphere-collision-detection-r1234)

http://www.essentialmath.com/CollisionDetection.pps

Answer (score 1):

You could also look into various Open Source Game engines, and see how they handle collision, like for example [panda3d](http://www.panda3d.org/).
You might also take a peek into sources of physics engines like [ODE](http://www.ode.org/) or [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.org)